How do I split addresses with no commas, and irregular layouts in a Pandas data frame?
I have a column in a data frame like this (it includes many more address):



Address




287 Andover Pl Robbinsville NJ 08691


1 Oxford Ct Princeton Jct NJ 08550


244 N Post Rd Princeton Jct NJ 08550


3 Gates Ct West Windsor NJ 08550



How can I separate these addresses into 2 columns, so that it has the number and street address in one column, and the city, state, zip in another like this:



Address 1
Address 2




287 Andover Pl
Robbinsville NJ 08691


1 Oxford Ct
Princeton Jct NJ 08550


244 N Post Rd
Princeton Jct NJ 08550


3 Gates Ct
West Windsor NJ 08550



I have tried doing this by separating everything by space from the right, but some towns include two words in their names, and thus this way does not work.
# put zip code into separate column
        clean_df[['prop_addressLine1','Owner Zip']] = clean_df['Owner Address'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)

        # separate street, city, and state into their own columns:
        clean_df[['Owner Street','Owner City','Owner State']] = clean_df['prop_addressLine1'].str.rsplit(' ', n=2, expand=True)

I was thinking of separating everything into separate columns by space, but there are irregular spaces, and I have not figured out how to make it work.

Parsing free-form addresses is an NLP task.

This can't be done by simple pattern matching. You need something that knows the names of streets and cities. Otherwise, how do you expect it to know that N Post Rd Princeton isn't a street name?

One option is to use the street type abbreviations (Ct/Pl/Rd) as delimiters and to extract the two parts:
df[['Address 1', 'Address 2']] = (df['Address'].str
                                  .extract('^(.*?(?:Pl|Ct|Rd)) (.*)$')
                                 )

If you want to handle more complex addresses, you'll need a parser. For example with usaddress:
import usaddress

def address_split(addr):
    address1 = []
    address2 = []
    flag = False
    for val, k in usaddress.parse(addr):
        if k == 'PlaceName':
            flag = True
        if flag:
            address2.append(val)
        else:
            address1.append(val)
    return ' '.join(address1), ' '.join(address2)


df['Address 1'], df['Address 2'] = list(zip(*map(address_split, df['Address'])))

Output:
                                Address       Address 1               Address 2
0  287 Andover Pl Robbinsville NJ 08691  287 Andover Pl   Robbinsville NJ 08691
1    1 Oxford Ct Princeton Jct NJ 08550     1 Oxford Ct  Princeton Jct NJ 08550
2  244 N Post Rd Princeton Jct NJ 08550   244 N Post Rd  Princeton Jct NJ 08550
3      3 Gates Ct West Windsor NJ 08550      3 Gates Ct   West Windsor NJ 08550

Intermediate with usaddress.parse:
# usaddress.parse('244 N Post Rd Princeton Jct NJ 08550')

[('244', 'AddressNumber'),
 ('N', 'StreetNamePreDirectional'),
 ('Post', 'StreetName'),
 ('Rd', 'StreetNamePostType'),
 ('Princeton', 'PlaceName'),
 ('Jct', 'PlaceName'),
 ('NJ', 'StateName'),
 ('08550', 'ZipCode')]


Thanks for the reply! If I use the street abbreviations, I would need to list each one. Is there a quick way to do that for large datasets? Seems like the parser would be the way to go, as this list is only a sample, and there are hundreds of addresses with different cities, street abbreviations, etc. If I use the parser, do I need to install any additional programs? If so, what would be the name?

Without seeing the full dataset, it's difficult to comment on the first approach. Of course you might need trial and error. For the library, if you follow the link in my answer you'll see that you need to install it with pip install usaddress.

Thanks! Yes, I realized that after I sent back my response. I will go that route. I think it would be the best choice for this scenario.
